# In what way does “en cela” refer to its antecedent in “en cela je vous demande de”?

Tags: pronoms, expressions-idiomatiques, prépositions

> Je vous demande d’être révolutionnaires, d’aller à contre-courant ;
>   oui, en cela je vous demande de vous révolter contre cette culture du
>   provisoire
>
> <sup>[Source: la Croix](http://www.la-croix.com/Religion/Actualite/L-Eglise-que-veut-le-pape-Francois-2013-07-30-992764)</sup>

Does *en cela* mean “as far as your going against the tide is concerned”, with *cela* replacing *d’aller à contre-courant* and even *d’être révolutionnaires*?

Comment: @Gilles A question for you: aren't pronouns part of grammar? According to every grammar of any language I have ever seen in my life, they are. So, if they are, why _delete_ the tag called grammaire instead of adding it to the tags called vocabulaire and pronoms?

Comment: It depends. If you ask which pronoun to use in a particular type of complement, that's grammar. If you ask what the meaning of a phrase that happens to contain a pronoun, that isn't grammar.

Comment: @Gilles: on this one I really don't see a reason to use *vocabulary*, the question is about *en cela* which is an adverbial group made of a preposition and a pronoun which admit a proposition as antecedent. This is a grammar question.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez “Does XXX mean …” is vocabulary, not grammar. “With cela replacing …” could be grammar (syntax analysis), but as it happens this is an idiom.

Comment: @Gilles: IMO, it's not an even idiom, it could be considered a natural combination of a preposition with a pronoun. *Pour cela*, *en cela*, *sans cela* all make sense. And it's not vocabulary, lexical roots are not involved, all are systematically build from prepositions and pronouns. Grammatical constructions have a “meaning” too, they have some semantic influence, otherwise we would not use any.

Comment: OK, so what is it: idiom or autonomous word? For the sake of this otherwise interesting debate, would you please support your claims by quoting some authoritative source saying that _en cela_ is either an idiom, or a combination of a preposition and a pronoun? I would really like to see some hard evidence for either version.

Comment: @Gilles: [Grammar](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/grammaire) is more than syntax analysis to me. And I agree that *vocabulary* could generally include any kind of word, but don't think we should also include “tool words” in the scope of the tag, or anything could be tagged as vocabulary, since French is mostly made out of words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*En cela* reprend toute la proposition précédent le point-virgule. On pourrait ainsi réécrire la phrase exemple de la façon suivante :

> Je vous demande d’être révolutionnaires, d’aller à contre-courant. En vous demandant cela je vous demande donc de vous révolter contre cette culture du provisoire.

Il s'agit d'un moyen ["de souligner avec force" (voir sens B- 4.)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cela).

Comment: So in your reformulation _cela_ means _all these things_. By the way, do you know anyone who's knowledgeable about ancient Greek?

Comment: Yes, this is what it means. I'll translate my answer later on, I simply forgot sorry. About the ancient Greek, I just have no idea.

Comment: Thanks. You don't have to translate your answer into English because I can understand it. That's my problem: I can understand French infinitely better than I can speak it or write it. Anyway, very kind of you for the offer.

Answer (score 2):

*Sans cela*, *pour cela*, *de cela*, *à cela*, etc. sont autant de constructions formées systématiquement à partir d'une préposition et d'un pronom démonstratif.

*En cela* est un groupe adverbial formé de la même façon avec la préposition *en*, mais il faut bien noter que dans l'exemple donné le *en* est celui qui forme le **gérondif**. Parmi les différents rôles que peut endosser cette préposition, celui-ci permet aussi la combinaison avec un pronom. Ce pronom référence alors un procédé décrit antérieurement, le plus souvent matérialisé dans le discours par une ou plusieurs propositions, comme ici « demander d’être révolutionnaires ou d'aller à contre-courant ».

Le sens de « en cela » s'explicite  alors par « en demandant d'être révolutionnaire ou d'aller à contre courant ». Le gérondif français « en faisant quelque chose » se traduit le plus souvent en anglais soit par « doing something » soit par « by doing something » soit par « in doing something ». Le sens de « en cela » varie donc respectivement de « doing this/so » à « by this » ou « in this ». Dans cet exemple, je pense que « in this » est la traduction qui convient le mieux.

Answer (score 0):

« En cela » est un idiome. Le pronom « cela » n'a pas vraiment de référent grammatical, seulement un référent sémantique. Autrement dit, « cela » désigne de qui a été dit précédemment. On pourrait le remplacer par « de cette manière », mais le sens n'est pas tout à fait le même : « de cette manière » insiste sur la méthode, alors que « en cela » insiste sur l'action elle-même.

Comment: If _en cela_ is an idiom, how can it be translated into English? Perhaps it has no fixed translation, but, in principle, can it be rendered as _all this_?

Comment: @indoxica “In this” or “by this”, rather. Or “thus”.