# Quels sont les sens respectifs de « culture du provisoire » et de « culture provisoire » ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, articles

Cette question s'appuie sur [celle de l'utilisateur indoxica](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7114/in-what-way-does-en-cela-refer-to-its-antecedent-in-en-cela-je-vous-demande-d):

> Je vous demande d’être révolutionnaires, d’aller à contre-courant ;
>   oui, en cela je vous demande de vous révolter contre cette **culture du
>   provisoire**. [Source](http://www.la-croix.com/Religion/Actualite/L-Eglise-que-veut-le-pape-Francois-2013-07-30-992764)

Pourquoi **culture du provisoire** et non pas **culture provisoire** ? Je suis conscient que **provisoire** fonctionne en tant que nom masculin et adjectif.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comme vous l'avez souligné le mot *provisoire* peut s'utiliser en tant qu'adjectif ou en tant que nom commun. Vous devrez noter également que le nom commun *culture* a plusieurs sens (8 au total).

Dans cette phrase, le mot *culture* a le sens suivant :

> (Figuré) Application que l'on met à perfectionner les sciences, les
>   arts, à développer les facultés humaines.
>   *La culture **de** l’esprit, **de** l’intelligence*. [(source)](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/culture)

Dans votre phrase, *provisoire* n'est pas un adjectif (auquel cas il n'aurait pas été précédé de l'article ***du***), mais bien un nom commun (masculin), et Il est donc précédé de l'article correspondant (*du*).

> Quelque chose de provisoire. 
>   *Il a gagné le provisoire. Introduire un
>   provisoire. Ce n’est là qu’un provisoire. Rester dans le provisoire.
>   Sortir du provisoire*. [(source)](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/provisoire)

---

As you pointed the word *provisoire* can be used as an adjective or as a common name. You will also note that the word *culture* has several meanings (8 in total).

In this sentence the word *culture* has the following meaning:

> (Transitive) Application that makes it perfect science, the arts,
>   developing human faculties. 
> *The cultivation of **the** mind, the cultivation of **the** intellect.*

In your sentence, the word *provisoire* is not an adjective (in which case it would not have been preceded by the article ***the***), but a common name (masculine), and it is preceded by the article (*the*).

> Something temporary. 
>   *Introduce a temporary. This
>   is just a temporary. Staying in the interim.*

Comment: Je vous suis reconnaissant. J'ai plussoyé.

Comment: J'espère que mon changement de l'acceptation vous aidera.

Answer (score 5):

Dans *culture provisoire*, la culture elle même est provisoire, éphémère, temporaire mais on ne connait pas son objet.

Dans *culture du provisoire*, la culture concerne le provisoire, l'éphémère, le temporaire, mais on n'indique rien quant à sa durée.

Comment: Je vous suis reconnaissant. J'ai plussoyé. Veuillez me permettre d'allouer les +15 à Chris car il détient bien moins de points.